# can't parse json to object in flutter

Tags: arrays, json, flutter

Seeking your help.

Actually, I've created an object model class. However, when I tried to parse the JSON response to the object model but error as below :

JSON Response

```
"value": [
    {
        "CardCode": "C20000",
        "CardName": "Maxi Teq",
        "DocCur": "AUD",
        "DocEntry": 793,
        "DocNum": 793,
        "DocTotal": 99.0,
        "DocType": "I",
        "U_Driver": "addon",
        "U_GLINK": "https://goo.gl/maps/tQJh7Zj9fpUzQqcv9"
    },
    {
        "CardCode": "C20000",
        "CardName": "Maxi Teq",
        "DocCur": "AUD",
        "DocEntry": 795,
        "DocNum": 795,
        "DocTotal": 99.0,
        "DocType": "I",
        "U_Driver": "addon",
        "U_GLINK": "https://goo.gl/maps/tQJh7Zj9fpUzQqcv9"
    }
]
```

Model
All the variables are string, but the JSON response includes int.

```
  import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
  
  part 'order.g.dart';
  
  @JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
  class order {
    String? cardCode;
    String? cardName;
    String? docCur;
    String? docEntry;
    String? docNum;
    String? docTotal;
    String? docType;
    String? uDriver;
    String? uGLINK;
  
    order({this.cardCode, this.cardName, this.docCur, this.docEntry, this.docNum, this.docTotal, this.docType, this.uDriver, this.uGLINK});
  
    factory order.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> data) => _$orderFromJson(data);
  
    Map<String,dynamic> toJson() => _$orderToJson(this);
  }
```

Main Class

```
  Map<String, dynamic> orderMap = json.decode(orderJson);
  List<dynamic> orderList = orderMap["value"];

  print("Method-------------$orderList");
  
  List<order> list = orderList.map((val) =>  order.fromJson(val)).toList();
  print(list.toString());
```

Error Response

```
I/flutter (26244): [Instance of 'order', Instance of 'order', Instance of 'order', Instance of 'order', Instance of 'order']
```

Thank you

Comment: That is not an error. That is the result of: `print(list.toString());`

Comment: is your JSON was in this format ? 
{

Comment: is your JSON was in this format?

{
   "value": [
    {
        "CardCode": "C20000",
        "CardName": "Maxi Teq",
        "DocCur": "AUD",
        "DocEntry": 793,
        "DocNum": 793,
        "DocTotal": 99.0,
        "DocType": "I",
        "U_Driver": "addon",
        "U_GLINK": "https://goo.gl/maps/tQJh7Zj9fpUzQqcv9"
    },
  ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not an error. That is the result of: `print(list.toString());`

What you are lacking is a `toString()` method on the class `order`, so it just prints that you have a list of instances of type `order`.

Add something like this to your `order` class:

```
  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'order(cardCode: $cardCode, cardName: $cardName, docCur: $docCur, docEntry: $docEntry, docNum: $docNum, docTotal: $docTotal, docType: $docType, uDriver: $uDriver, uGLINK: $uGLINK)';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use orderList.elementAt(0) to get a map of value.